# XCode 6.1.1 debugger doesn't show value of NSString variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

Why is XCode's debugger not showing string values for `NSString*` variables?

Steps to reproduce: I created a new console app project; here is main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *myString = @"hi there";
        [myString length];// breakpoint here; cannot see value of myString in debugger.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint on `[myString length]`, I would expect to be able to see the value of `myString` in the debugger. It shows in the debugger as `null`.

Observations while trying other code situations:

- I am in debug build configuration; debugging symbols are working fine.
- I can use `po myString` in the lldb window to indeed see the correct value. Only the watch window continues to show `(null)`
- Nothing has been optimized away.
- Same behavior if I use a non-constant string.
- It works fine for other objects. For example I tried `NSDictionary*`, `NSArray*`, `NSMutableString*`.

Is this a bug in XCode 6.1.1? Am I missing something painfully obvious?

Comment: It probably is just a bug. It's not a very good debugger. Be glad you're not using Swift; things are even worse.